# Create columns based on number in another column

Tags: excel, vba

This one will be difficult for me to explain since i don't have the technical competence, so i thought you could help me.

Column 1 keeps data on each store in this way:

Store    -    ID    -     Profession 
 Store 1      25          Glazier, Electrician, Plumber 
Store 2      64          Damageservice
Store 3      96          Damageservice, Bricklayer

Based on the ID i would like to create columns for each profession in column 2. 
The profession is based on following data:

ProfessionID    Profession
1                       Plumber
8                       Electrician 
16                     Glazier
32                     Bricklayer
64                     Damageservice

e.g. Store 1 has ID 25 which means it contains profession (Glazier) 16 + (Electrician) 8 + (Plumber) 1 = 25.

I need a VBA code that analyses the ID and creates a line for each profession the store contains - In this way converts data from column 1 to columns 2 in this way:

e.g. for Store 1:

Store   -   ID   -   Profession 
Store 1     1        Plumber
Store 1     8        Electrician
Store 1     16      Glazier

I was thinking of using modulus, but my VBA is not strong.
How would you approach this? Solutions are also more than welcome. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx shows you how to do this.  Look at "Composite Values"

Comment: By column 1 and column 2 you mean sheet?

Comment: The logic seems incomplete. You would need more information to convert "ID25 - Glazier, Electrician, Plumber" into "1 Plumber". What information determines whether ID25 is a "1, 8 or 16" ?

In any case, from your explanation it looks like the ID is a count and could be a variable? next month ID25 can be 2 Plumber, 7 Electrician and 15 Glazier?